# How to determine the velocity of a robotic car using video analysis techniques?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Consider a self-driving robotic car, which is following lanes on a circular testbed. I want to determine the precise velocity of the car. I was thinking: Why not record a video of the car and then apply video processing techniques to determine its velocity.

Since I am a complete beginner to video processing, can somebody tell me what would be a good way of determining the velocity of a driving car in a video? Which are the topics I need to look into and what is the general approach?

Comment: You can have a look at this page on [visual odometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry)

Comment: In simplistic terms, speed is distance divided by time. Presumably you can determine the time from the video frame counter, so you need to determine the distance travelled by measuring it from the vehicle's position on the track.

Comment: Thx, guys! Two questions come to my mind when reading your comments: Firstly, is one camera sufficient? My robots are driving in a circle, but the velocity should be constant. Right now, I have only one camera available for recording a video. Second question: Is this related to object tracking? Or Edge Detection? I mean: Can you tell me the exact steps necessary to achieve this task?

Comment: You need [motion estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation), that can performed by different means. Then a good [camera calibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning) is required to properly convert a pixel position to a line in 3D space. You also need a knowledge of your (dynamic) camera position. And some basic projective geometry.

Comment: How many cameras you require will depend on their positions and with what granularity you need to know the speed. If the camera is positioned above the track looking down at it and covering the entire track, that may be all you need. If the camera is looking across the track like the finish line in horse-racing, you will only be able to determine the average speed over one whole lap which won't tell you if your robot accelerated or decelerated part way around.

Comment: ok guys, thx a lot again! What do you think is the amount of time needed to accomplish this task? I know this differs a lot individually, I just want a rough estimate. I am new to this topic as I said and still need to read a lot. Still, do you think 2 weeks is enough or is this ridiculously under-estimated and I need way more time ?

Comment: That is an unanswerable quiestion. You are going to be solving this problem yourself: it is only by you making some progress by actually trying to solve it that you will be able to improve the accuracy of your estimate of two weeks.